# Is it good practice to group methods into a more general method?

Tags: ios, swift, function, oop

I have a bit of setup work that needs to be done in `viewDidLoad`. I have added all my helper methods into a configure method, so that in `viewDidLoad`, I just call `configure()` and everything works. Is this good practice or is it seen as a bad practice of coupling code together.  Any tip is appreciated!

```
//configure() called in viewDidLoad
private func configure() {

    UserProvider.sharedInstance.fetchUser(with: AuthProvider.sharedInstance.currentUserId(), completionHandler: {
        user in
        guard let user = user else { return }
        self.currentUser = user

        self.setupViews(currentUser: user)

        self.setupLocation()
    })
}


private func setupViews(currentUser: User) {
    setupCollectionView()
    updateDatasource(currentUser: currentUser)
}


private func setupCollectionView() {
    collectionView.dataSource = datasource
    collectionView.delegate = datasource
}


private func updateDatasource(currentUser: User) {
    UserProvider.sharedInstance.fetchNearbyUsers(for: currentUser, completionHandler: { nearbyUsers in
        guard nearbyUsers.isEmpty == false else { return }
        self.datasource.update(with: nearbyUsers, collectionView: self.collectionView)
    })
}
```

Comment: one more suggestion. you must use 'weak self' if you are inside a closure/block.

Comment: @Gagan_iOS Can you provide a simple explanation why? I know it has to do with memory management and reference cycles, but haven't been able to really grasp it, which is why i didn't use 'weak self'. Thank you.

Comment: look at this Apple link https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH20-ID48   They have explained very well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's a good practice to  modularize your code into a function.

But the naming should be more readable and understable.

**How?**

Suppose in your same View controller you want to configure some **UI related change**. like navigation bar color, navigation title, etc.

And You want to change some contraint value.As well you want to configure network like what you are doing right now. So if you put all of your code into configure function that will create some misunderstanding.In that case, you can break down more like

```
func configureUI(){//write ui configuration here}
 func updateConstraintsValue() {//write constraints change code here}
 func configureAuth() { //write Authentication configuration code here}
```

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's actually pretty good because that way you can break down your code into smaller code which makes it easier for you to code and also for the person that might read the code. So yes this is a good practice. It doesn't affect the code at all, it just makes it easier for you and other.

Comment: Thanks for your insight.